# XeLaTeX long compilation time without mistake

Tags: xetex, compiling, fontspec

XeTeX long compilation time in this code !!! why

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.05]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
 Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Some more information about your OS and TeX distribution is needed. On my machine I get `real 0m1.167s`

Comment: I use texlive2016,  texmaker editor, I think that the problem in fontspec pachage.

Comment: How does your time compare with @egreg's?

Comment: On my pc I get  `0m28s`